# Difference between += for Integers/Strings and << For Arrays?

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I'm confused about the different results I'm getting when performing simple addition/concatenation on integers, strings and arrays in Ruby.  I was under the impression that when assigning variable b to a (see below), and then changing the value of a, that b would remain the same.  And it does so in the first two examples.  But when I modify Array a in the 3rd example, both a and b are modified.

```
a = 100
b = a
a+= 5
puts a
puts b
```

---

```
a = 'abcd'
b = a
a += 'e'
puts a
puts b
```

---

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a << 5
puts a.inspect
puts b.inspect
```

The following is what was returned in Terminal for the above code:

```
Ricks-MacBook-Pro:programs rickthomas$ ruby variablework.rb
105
100
abcde
abcd
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Ricks-MacBook-Pro:programs rickthomas$
```

I was given the following explanation by my programming instructor:

> Assigning something to a new variable is just giving it an additional label, it doesn't make a copy.
>
> It looks like += is a method, just like <<, and so you'd expect it to behave similarly. But in reality, it's "syntactic sugar", something added to the language to make things easier on developers.
>
> When you run a += 1, Ruby converts that to a = a + 1.
>
> In this case, we're not modifying the Fixnum in a. Instead, we're actually re-assigning on top of it, effectively blowing away the previous value of a.
>
> On the other hand, when you run b << "c", you're modifying the underlying Array by appending the String "c" to it.

My questions are these:

1) He mentions syntactic sugar, but isn't that also what << is, i.e. syntactic sugar for the .push method?

2) Why would it matter if += is syntactic sugar or a more formal method?  If there is some difference between the two, then doesn't that mean my previously-understood of syntactic sugar ("syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express") is incomplete, since this isn't its only purpose?

3) If assigning b to a doesn't make a copy of a, then why doesn't wiping away a's old value mean that b's old value is also wiped away for all 3 cases (Integer, String and Array)?

As you can see, I'm pretty turned around on something that I thought I understood until now.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: do you want us to explain why two different results?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu- yes, and I see you've already done so below.  The object_id explanation was helpful, thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see, names (variable names, like `a` and `b`) don't hold any values themselves. They simply *point* to a value. When you make an assignment

```
a = 5
```

then `a` now points to value 5, regardless of what it pointed to previously. This is important.

```
a = 'abcd'
b = a
```

Here both `a` and `b` point to the same string. But, when you do this

```
a += 'e'
```

It's actually translated to

```
a = a + 'e'
# a = 'abcd' + 'e'
```

So, name `a` is now bound to a new value, while `b` keeps pointing to "abcd".

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a << 5
```

There's no assignment here, method `<<` modifies existing array without replacing it. Because there's no replacement, both `a` and `b` still point to the same array and one can see the changes made to another.

Comment: So when I say a = 5 and b = a, I'm not actually pointing b to a, but rather pointing it to whatever a also points to.  But if I modify what a is pointing to, then there are now to different 'things' being pointed to- a's new item and b's old item.  Is this right?

Answer (score 3):

### The answer to 1) and 2) of your question:

The reason why `+=` is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) and `<<` is not is fairly simple: `+=` abstracts some of the syntactic expression: `a += 1` is just a short version of `a = a + 1`. `<<` is a method all by itself and is **not** an alias for `push`: [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) can only take one argument, whereas [`push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-push) can take an arbitrary number of arguments: I'm demonstrating this with send here, since `[1,2]<<(1,2)` is syntactically incorrect:

```
[1,2].send(:<<, 4, 5) #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

`push` appends all arguments to the array:

```
[1,2].push(4,5,6) #=> [1,2,4,5,6]
```

Therefore, `<<` is an irreplaceable part of the ruby array, since there is no equivalent method. One could argue that it is *some kind of* syntactic sugar for `push`, with disregard for the differences shown above, since it makes most operations involving appending elements to an array simpler and syntactically more recognizable.

If we go deeper and have a look at the different uses of `<<` throughout ruby:

- Push An Element to an array:

  ```
  [1,2] << 5
  ```
- concatenate a string to another, here, [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-concat) is actually an alias for [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-concat)

  ```
  "hello " << "world"
  ```
- Open up the singleton class and define a method on a class:

  ```
  class Foo
    class << self
      def bar
        puts 'baz'
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- And last but not least append `self` to `self` in Integers:

  ```
  1 << 2 #translates to ((1 + 1) + (1 + 1))
  ```

We can see that `<<` actually stands for *append* throughout ruby, since it always appears in a context where something is appended to something already existing. I would therefore rather argue that `<<` is a significant part of the ruby syntax and **not** syntactic sugar.

### And the answer to 3)

The reason why `b`'s assignment is not modified (or wiped of its old value, as you put it) if you use the `+=` operator is just that `a += 1`, as a short for `a = a + 1`, reassigns `a`'s value and therefore assigns a new object along with that. `<<` is modifying the original object. You can easily see this using the [`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id):

```
a = 1
b = a
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> true

a += 1
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> false

a = [1,2]
b = a
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> true
a << 3
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> true
```

There are also some caveats to `Integer` instances (`100`, `101`) and so on: the same number is always the same object, since it does not make any sense to have multiple instances of, for example `100`:

```
a = 100
b = a
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> true
a += 1
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> false
a -= 1
b.object_id == a.object_id #=> true
```

This also shows that the value, or the `Integer` instance (`100`) is just *assigned* to the variable, so the variable itself is not an object, it just points to it.

Answer (score 1):

> > [`String#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) :: `str + other_str → new_str` Concatenation—Returns a new String containing `other_str` concatenated to `str`.
> >
> > [`String#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) :: `str << integer → str` : Append—Concatenates the given object to `str`.

`<<` doesn't create the new object, where as `+` does.

***Sample1:***

```
a = 100
p a.object_id
b = a
p b.object_id
a+= 5
p a.object_id
p b.object_id
puts a
puts b
```

***Output:***

```
201
201
211
201
105
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example:

```
a = 100
b = a
a+= 5
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = 100
b = a
a = 100 + 5
```

Afterwards `a` holds a reference to `105` and `b` still holds a reference to `100`. This is how *assignment* works in Ruby.

You expected `+=` to change the object instance `100`. In Ruby, however (quoting the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html)):

> There is effectively only one `Fixnum` object instance for any given integer value

So there's only one object instance for `100` and another (but always the same) one for `105`. Changing `100` to `105` would change *all* `100`'s to `105`. Therefore, it is not possible to modify these instances in Ruby, they are *fixed*.

A `String` instance on the other hand can be modified and unlike `Integer` there can be multiple instances for the same sequence of bytes:

```
a = "abcd"
b = "abcd"
a.equal? b # returns true only if a and b are the same object
# => false
```

`a << "e"` concatenates `"e"` to `a`, thus changing the receiver: `a` is still referencing the same object instance.

Other methods like `a += "e"` return (and assign) a *new* `String`: `a` would reference this new instance afterwards.

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) is pretty clear:

> #### str + other_str → new_str
>
> Concatenation—Returns a new `String` containing `other_str` concatenated to `str`.
>
> #### str << obj → str
>
> Append—Concatenates the given object to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your questions.

**1)** No, the `<<` method is not syntactic sugar for `push`.  They are both methods with different names.  You can have objects in Ruby that define one but not the other (for example [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)).

**2)** For a normal method like `<<`, *the only thing that can happen as a result of `a << x` is that the object that `a` is pointing to gets modified*.  The statements `a << x` or `a.push(x)` cannot create a new object and change the variable `a` to point at it.  That's just how Ruby works.  This kind of thing is called "calling a method".

The reason that `+=` being syntactic sugar matters is that means it can be used to modify a variable without mutating the old object that the variable used to point to.  Consider `a += x`.  That statement **can** modify what object a is pointing to because it is syntactic sugar for an actual *assignment* to `a`:

```
a = a + x
```

There are two things happening above.  First the `+` method is called on `a` with one argument of `x`.  Then the return value of the `+` method, whatever it is, is assigned to the variable `a`.

**3)** The reason that your Array case is different is because you chose to mutate the array instead of creating a new array.  You could have used `+=` to avoid mutating the array.  I think that these six examples that will clear things up for you and show you what is possible in Ruby:

### Strings without mutations

```
a = "xy"
b = a
a += "z"
p a  # => "xyz"
p b  # => "xy"
```

### Strings with mutations

```
a = "xy"
b = a
a << "z"
p a  # => "xyz"
p b  # => "xyz"
```

### Arrays without mutations

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a += [4]
p a  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
p b  # => [1, 2, 3]
```

### Arrays with mutations

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.concat [4]
p a  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
p b  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

### Integers without mutations

```
a = 100
b = a
a += 5
puts a   # => 105
puts b   # => 100
```

### Integers with mutations

Mutating an integer is actually not possible in Ruby.  Writing `a = b = 89` actually does create two copies of the number 89, and the number cannot be mutated ever.  Only a few, special types of objects behave like this.

### Conclusion

You should think of a variable as just a name, and an object as a nameless piece of data.

**All** objects in Ruby can be used in an immutable way where you never actually modify the contents of an object.  If you do it that way, then you don't have to worry about the `b` variable in our examples changing on its own; `b` will always point to the same object and that object will never change.  The variable `b` will only change when you do some form of `b = x`.

**Most** objects in Ruby can be mutated.  If you have several variables referring to the same object and you choose to mutate the object (e.g. by calling `push`), then that change will affect all the variables that are pointing to the object.  You cannot mutate Symbols and Integers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the above answers explain the reason. Note also that if you want to ensure `b` is no pointer, you can use `b = a.dup` instead of `b=a`  (dup for duplicate )

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and answer your question to the best of my ability.

Yes, both are "sugars" but they work differently and as Sergio Tulentsev said, `<<` it's not really a sugar but it's an alias.

And those works as an alias in Unix like languages, it's a shorter shorthand for something named after your liking.

So for the first scenario: `+=` basically what's happening is that you're saying:

```
for the value 100 assign label 'a'.
for label 'b' assign the value of label 'a'.
for label 'a' take the value of label 'a' and add 5 to label 'a's value and return a new value
print label 'a' #this now holds the value 105
print label 'b' #this now holds the value 100
```

Under the hood of Ruby this has to do with the `+=` returning a new String when that happens.

For the second scenario: `<<` it's saying:

```
for value [1,2,3,4] assign label 'a'  
for label 'b' assign the value of label 'a'
for label 'a' do the '<<' thing on the value of label 'a'.
print label 'a'
print label 'b'
```

And if you're applying the `<<` to a string it will modify the existing object and append to it.

So what's different. Well the difference is that the `<<` sugar doesn't act like this:

```
a is the new value of a + 5
```

it acts like this:

```
5 into the value of 'a'
```

2) Because the way you use the syntactic sugar in this case is making it easier for the
developer to read and understand the code. It's a shorthand.

Well, shorthands, if you call them that instead, do serve diffrent purposes.
The syntactic sugar isn't homogenous ie. it doesn't work the same way for all "sugars".

3) On wiping values:

It's like this.

```
put value 100 into the label 'a'
put the value of label 'a' into label 'b'
remove label 'a' from the value.
```

So

```
a = 100
b = a
a = nil
puts a
puts b
=> 100
```

Variables in Ruby doesn't hold values they point to values!

Comment: "you're actually copying the value" - no, you're not. No copy. Unless, of course, you were trying to say that "value" being copied is a pointer. In which case you didn't do a good job at explaining.

Comment: Thanks! :) I'll rephrase my answer immediately! I was trying to be overly explaining but I see what you mean now, sorry!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev better? If not i'll just delete my answer!

Comment: What's the difference between "pass by reference" and your next sentence? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i hope that does it! :) I'll bow to the superiority if you think I confuse more than help! :)

Comment: So, is ruby "pass by value" or is it not? You contradict yourself :)

Comment: Argh, I thought I had it removed! This was my worst answer of all times. Sorry for this!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're a cool dude, thanks for the help! and sorry for troubling you! :)